# How to make an axios.post request with Basic Authentification using React.Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm making an axios.post request with React.Js, Redux and Basic Auth, and i found this error.
How can i fix it please ?

I'm using: Front (React.Js), Back (SpringBoot), Data Base (MySQL)

This is my code:

```js
const allDev = []
export const createGps = (gpsDevice) => {
  let uri = "http://62.171.157.49:8081/api/devices";
            
  let h = new Headers();
  h.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  let encoded = window.btoa('yahya.mess95@gmail.com:Yahya@2027');
  let auth = `Basic ${  encoded}`;
  h.append('Authorization', auth );
  console.log( auth );
  
  let req = new Request(
    uri, 
    gpsDevice,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: h,
      credentials: 'include'
    }
  );
    return (dispatch) => {
      axios.post(req)
      .then( (response)=>{
        console.log(response)
          if(response.ok){
              dispatch(notifAdd())
              console.log(response.json())
              return response.json();
          }
          throw new Error('BAD HTTP stuff');
          
      })
      .then( (jsonData) =>{
          console.log(jsonData);
          JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4);
            return {
              ...gpsDevice,
              allDev: [...allDev, {...gpsDevice}]
            }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("error adding dev: ", err))
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYVmb.png)

Comment: What is the error? Oh, it's in the image. 404 means the resource doesn't exist, so, naught to do with authentication

Comment: your code seems to be alright, the post URL seems to be incorrect as given in the error. Fix that and see the result

Comment: Well the credentials work

Comment: Try console logging ```req``` and make sure the path to your backend is correct.

Comment: Oh, does axios accept native Request object as an argument? does Request constructor take three arguments now? I'm sure it's two at most? Mixing axios with native fetch objects looks odd

Answer (score 0):

I work with the APIs of Traccar.